# get a the row number in a data step using sas

Tags: sas

Is there a way to get to do a over partition to get the row number on sas?
In sql I would go like:

```
  Select region,company, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY region ORDER BY Name)
    From companyData;
```

I want to do this in a data set preferably

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that in a data step easily by using the by statement, it and the do a running sum :

> `proc sort data=myData;    by region name; run;`

```
Data myData;
Set myData;
By company;
if first. company then n=1;
   else n+1;
run;
```

Also to ennmuarete all the obs you can use the built in features:

```
DATA COMPANYDATA;
SET COMPANYDATA;
ROW_NUM=_N_;    
RUN;
```

As Joe mentioned you might want to set the format for your row_num depending on how much obs you would get within that grouping.

Comment: @Joe good catch ! and completely agree on both, I edited it! thanks!

Comment: yeah, you are mgith be an overhead in this case

Comment: This answer is missing the sorting step that Bob mentions below.  Without adding the additional sorting step you are not guaranteed to get the same results as the SQL example above.

Answer (score 3):

To duplicate the SQL `ROW_NUMBER` Windowing function, you must sort the data set by **both** the `PARTITION` and `ORDER BY` clauses.  In a subsequent data step, `SET` the sorted data set **only** by the partition variable(s) and use the `FIRST.` automatic variable control assign the new row number variable.

Here is a solution for your stated example:

```
proc sort data=companyData;
   by region name;
run;
data want;
   set companyData;
      by region;
   if first.region then row_number = 1;
                   else row_number + 1;
run;
```

Notice the `BY` statement in the data step corresponds to the `PARTITION BY` clause in ANSI SQL but the `PROC SORT` step also sorts by the columns in the `ORDER BY` clause.  Also note that if the query you are "migrating" contains an `ORDER BY` SQL clause, you must follow this up with another `PROC SORT` step.